# Get empty value of Json Array Volley Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I create a method to get json from server...And I need the data to make conditional including the empty array with result -> '[ ]'

So, as my code below

```
String url = "http://lineitopkal.com/android/api.php?case=status&id_user="+id_user;
    JsonArrayRequest schoolReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    User user = new User();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            checkin_sekolah = obj.getString("status_checkin_sekolah");
                            checkin_wajah = obj.getString("status_checkin_wajah");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(checkin_sekolah.equals("1") && checkin_wajah.equals("0")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FaceVerificationActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id_sekolah",id_sekolah);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if(checkin_sekolah.equals("1") && checkin_wajah.equals("1")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id_sekolah",id_sekolah);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else if(response.length()==0){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id_sekolah",id_sekolah);
                            intent.putExtra("nama",nama);
                            intent.putExtra("long", longi);
                            intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(schoolReq);
}
```

I need to get the empty array '[ ]' to perform the task. Anyone know how to do that? Cuz what I did doesn't seem work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to handle the empty JSON array case?
In your code, your condition for the "for-loop" is `response.length()` which will be 0 if the JSON array is empty. 
You can try to wrap the entire for loop like this

```
     if(response.length()>0){
         // Paste your for-loop here ( JSON array is not empty)

     } else {
         // Handle empty JSON array here
     }
```

I am not sure if you are asking for this or not. Hope this help